# Fix dlib installation error in Windows 10 VSCode

Tags: python, dlib

I want to use `dlib` with python for image recognition. I have the python app running great with OpenCV on Windows 10, but when I want to install dlib from the cmd it gives me this following error :

What should I do ?
This happen when I try `py -m pip install dlib`

````
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Richard>py -m pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.1.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\Users\Richard>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Dlib is problematic to install using pip.
First try updating the setuptools

```
python -m pip install -U setuptools
```

You dont have cmake installed. Install cmake using

```
python -m pip install cmake
```

After that re-run the command

```
python -m pip install dlib
```

If it doesn't work then you have to use conda to install dlib. Use

```
conda activate <env>
python -m pip install cmake
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Conda install dlib like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did as you said but this happen:
```(base) C:\Users\Richard>conda install -c conda-forge dlib
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /```

Comment: Hi, can you please show the full error stack? and after retrying with flexible solve it should have installed dlib. If it didnt then please install cmake first, using **pip install cmake**.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Hmm that's all happened when I use conda to install dlib. And I have already installed cmake btw.

Comment: @TuanDuy install dlib using conda and show me the full error stack please.

Comment: Here it is: 
(base) C:\Users\Richard>conda install -c conda-forge dlib Retrieving notices: ...working... done Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: /